# How do I persist a Java property of type Object using Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, orm, annotations

I have a Java class with a property like this

```
private Object myObj;
```

When I try to save the class using Hibernate annotations, I get the rather confusing error message "property mapping has wrong number of columns".

What is the correct approach to persisting a class containing a generic property such as this?

Comment: The only way I know of is serialization, and I don't recommend this.  Everytime you compile your app, the seralized version of the object in the database could become obsolete and not retreivable.

Comment: one question is: what's forcing you to use `Object` as the type for this specific field? Couldn't you use a more specific type instead?

Comment: @afielden: How would you like this to work? What would be your ideal end result, in terms of the database ?

Comment: I agree, it's not ideal, and I thought Hibernate may have some problems with this. The code is not mine, I'm just implementing the persistence layer using Hibernate. The idea is that the Object property may contain a wide variety of data, including but not limited to image and video. I guess they want a very flexible solution.

Comment: Yes, but how would you like to see it represented in the database? One column or several? It's own table? What datatypes would the columns be? When solving ORM puzzles, you need to think like a relational database, not a java developer.

Comment: This is something I will have to discuss with the other developers, as I've just joined the project. It's been suggested to me that this property should be converted to a byte array before storing in the database. I'm not sure how this would be implemented with Hibernate though.

Comment: @skaffman, I'd agree with you on the "ORM puzzles", although the "puzzles" should be the only case when one should think as a relational database and not as a java (OOP) developer :)

Answer (score 4):

As you said, the object can be image, video, and more.

If it is supposed to have only binary data, you can create another class, and transfer the data from this one. In the process of transferring you can convert the `Object` to `byte[]` (depending on the concrete type), and use a Lob data type (`@Lob`) for mapping it.

To extend this, if not only binary data is to be supported, your new object can have 2 fields - one in case of binary, and one (or more) in case of other types.

Anyway, the object as it is now, represents a quite unintelligent design, and it cannot be persisted properly without hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a generic Object attribute if you can help it. My first brush with Hibernate meant inheriting a project with oodles of things like this, and it was a world of pain. As Zoidberg says, using Object means that your model isn't easily serialised / versioned (an understatement if I'm honest).

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of your property:

```
private byte[] myObj;
```

This worked for me with Fluent NHibernate (albeit in C#) and an SQL field type of *varbinary(max)*.

You can then expose this as an image, video, or whatever.  An example of converting to an image in Java:

```
ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(myObj));
```