# Saving of grails domain object with an attribute type object fails

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails, groovy

I'm trying to save a domain object with grails 2.3.3 But it is not saved. How can I save it and why is it not saving?

The domain code:

```
package berg
import nl.jappieklooster.Log

class FieldValue {
    Object value

    public String toString(){
        Log.debug "Field value: {0}", value
        return value.toString()
    }  
    static constraints = {
    }  
}
```

The code that saves:

```
// an extract from the bootsrap file
def init = { servletContext ->
    def blueFV = new FieldValue(value: Color.blue)        
    def smallFV = new FieldValue(value: "small")
    def fieldVals = [blueFV, smallFV]
    saveData(fieldVals,berg.FieldValue)
}
public void saveData(List list, Class type){
    def wholeList = type.list() ?: []

    println("Started with adding the "+type.getName()+" classes.")

    int saved = 0;
    int failed = 0;

    if(!wholeList){
        list.each{ i ->
            if(i.validate()){
                i.save(flush:true, failOnError: true)
                saved++
            }
            else{
                println("! - - - Warning: '"+i.toString()+"' could not be created! - - - !")
                failed++
            }
        }
        if(failed > 0)//if one fails, let the message appear more clearly
            println(".v.v.")
        println("When saving the "+type.getName()+" classes: "+saved+" were saved, "+failed+" failed to be saved.")
        if(failed > 0)
            println(".^.^.")
    }
}
```

The entire value column does not show up in the database

Comment: What's Grails supposed to do with the `Object`?  Serialization is a poor solution in general.  Would you expect it to convert things to a `byte[]`?  But then how is it supposed to get the original object back?

Comment: I tried the byte[] idea, when i read this anwser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941191/how-do-i-persist-a-java-property-of-type-object-using-hibernate it could be done with input output streams in the accesors, but its not realy relevant any more, because it was imposible to design an user interface for this design. So we changed it to string.