# How to write Mapping for Object type in Hibernate by using annotation is it possible to store object type data in Table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I have a entity class that having Object type as variable how to write mapping for the same.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="demo") 
 public class Transaction implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "tid")
        private long tid;   

        Object gentemplate ;

        Object coretemplate;

        //getter and setter;
 }
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question, its not clear eg: towhich table you want to add mapping

Comment: in demo table  only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I persist a Java property of type Object using Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941191/how-do-i-persist-a-java-property-of-type-object-using-hibernate)

Comment: But i didn't find  any exact solution  there